# AWS CloudFront Invalidate only objects in the root directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

Is there a way to invalidate only the objects at root level in a AWS CloudFront distribution.

Let's assume that I have the following distribution. I would like to be able to invalidate `index.html`, `photo1.jpg`, `photo2.jpg`, but not `subdir/` and the files in it.

```
index.html
photo1.jpg
photo2.jpg
subdir/
   photo3.jpg
   photo2.jpg
```

Comment: I think adding just the `/` would do the job, isn't it

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: How about you just mention those files? for example /index.html /photo1.jpg etc

Comment: @kru, I can have several hundreds of files. I am looking to only have one path, to keep invalidation costs reasonable

Answer (score 1):

You can try invalidating by grouping file names into common prefixes.

In your example above, the following paths will work

- /index*
- /photo*

Unfortunately, Cloudfront requires the wildcard (*) to be at the end of the paths, so you can't invalidate by object extensions.

Ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidation-specifying-objects-paths

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, the thing you can do is to invalidate files with certain prefix for example

`/logo*`

Will invalidate only files with that name and different extension like `logo.png`, `logo.jpg`, `logo.gif`, etc. But if you have a directory called `logo` it will be invalidated too